# Sabre SDK for Nodejs

Tags: node.js, sabre

I'm looking for a nodejs wrapper for the Sabre Dev Studio APIs so that I can make bookings from my app via Sabre.

I was looking at the npm package [sabre-dev-studio npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sabre-dev-studio). However, I think it only applies for the REST APIs and the sabre documentation does not list any REST based APIs for booking. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Currently bookings are only supported via the SOAP interface

Answer (score 0):

So I have run into this. The SABRE REST APIs are there, but they didn't really finish the documentation. Which is frustrating. I would give them a call to go over. Keep in mind, you can almost all of the transactions in REST, but the workflows are a little different.

Comment: how do you get access to the APIs? I've tried contacting them but they don't seem to give any response